# MVC Create a record issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] ContentPageNav contentToCreate)
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            ContentPageNav content = contentToCreate;
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

What am I missing that the record is not getting inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dc.ContentPageNavs.InsertOnSubmit(contentToCreate);
```

Comment: there is no add function available

Comment: what are you using for your ORM?  It looked like Linq to Sql?  IN any case, there should be some step that you're adding your newly created item to the data context.  In Linq to Sql there should be a collection property on the data context that has an Add method like I described. If not, somethings wrong w/ your linq to sql classes

Comment: Yes I am using Linq to sql classes

Comment: Got it buddy. I was missing a line of code.

 dc.ContentPageNavs.InsertOnSubmit(contentToCreate);
            dc.SubmitChanges();

Comment: ah, my bad, been a while since I used LInq to Sql, the syntax I used was EF.  Glad it worked out for you anyway